# When a compiler can infer a template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

Sometimes it works sometimes not:

```
template <class T> 
void f(T t) {}

template <class T>
class MyClass {
public:
  MyClass(T t) {}
};

void test () {
  f<int>(5);
  MyClass<int> mc(5);
  f(5);
  MyClass mc(5); // this doesn't work
}
```

Is there a way to hack around the example above? I.e. force the compiler to infer the template parameter from constructor parameter.

Will this be fixed in the future, or is there a good reason not to?

What is the general rule when compiler can infer template parameter?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Template parameters can be inferred for *function templates* when the parameter type can be deduced from the template parameters

So it can be inferred here:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T t);

template <typename T>
void f(std::vector<T> v);
```

but not here:

```
template <typename T>
T f() {
  return T();
}
```

And not in *class templates*.

So the usual solution to your problem is to create a wrapper function, similar to the standard library function `std::make_pair`:

```
  template <class T>
    class MyClass {
    public:
        MyClass(T t) {}
        void print(){
            std::cout<<"try MyClass"<<std::endl;
        }
    };

    template <typename T>
    MyClass<T> MakeMyClass(T t) { return MyClass<T>(t); }
```

and then call `auto a = MakeMyClass(5);` to instantiate the class.

Comment: +1, thorough. Minor nit: I suggest changing "when the parameter type is dependant" to "when a parameter type is dependent".

Comment: void f(typename T::const_iterator t); << here, T appears in a undeducible context. even when calling it with a vector<int>::const_iterator, for example, it won't be able to deduce vector<int> for T. the reason is that the meaning of ::const_iterator depends on T. but T again depends on the meaning of ::const_iterator. that's why boost::implicit_cast is coded like this: template<typename T> T implicit_cast(typename identity<T>::type t) { return t; } here again, we have an undeducible context.

Comment: Standard-ref is 14.8.2.4/4 (latest c++1x draft has it located at 14.9.2.5/5 - fixing also some of the shortcomings of the wording in the current standard). :) cheers

Comment: Duh, you're right, of course. Don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: This answer is now outdated. It is possible to infer class template parameters [in C++17](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction).

Comment: This does not answer the questions `Will this be fixed in the future, or is there a good reason not to?

What is the general rule when compiler can infer template parameter?`

Answer (score 8):

Read up on [Template Argument Deduction](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/409) (and [ADL or Koenig lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_dependent_name_lookup)).

Comment: This is a link only answer, consider improving this answer by providing the relevant information from the referenced material.

Answer (score 1):

Since C++20, it is possible to [infer the types of function parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60355539/975097) using `auto`:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>

auto print_stuff(auto x, auto y) 
{ 
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << y << std::endl;
}

int main() 
{ 
    print_stuff(3,"Hello!");
    print_stuff("Hello!",4);
    return 0; 
}
```