# C++ - rules around function template instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, function, instantiation, overloading

I am learning function templates just now and I wanted to research a bit rules of function templates instantiation. So I've written the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename>
int check(int x) {
  return x * 2;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << check<double>(10) << std::endl; // #1
  std::cout << check<>(10) << std::endl;         // #2
  std::cout << check(10) << std::endl;            // #3
  return 0;
}
```

The lines #1, #2 and #3 are not compiled all together, each try I leave only one of them and comment the rest. 
So, when #1 is enabled, I have no compilation errors and the correct answer "20" is printed. As I understand, **"check<"double">"** invokes template instantiation mechanism so **"int check(int)"** function is really created (the type of template parameter doesn't have any influence). 
When #3 is enabled, I have a compilation error **"error: no matching function for call to 'check(int)'"**, which is reasonable, since I am trying to call to **"check(int)"** function which doesn't exist. My question is regarding #2 case: in this case I get the same **"error: no matching function for call to 'check(int)'"**. Shouldn't call **"check<>(10)"** trigger template instantiation mechanism as well?

Comment: "_Shouldn't call "check<>(10)" trigger template instantiation mechanism as well?_" The answer to your question is: with what argument?

Answer (score 1):

You don't put any template parameter in the <>. How can compiler know which template function to instantiate? Please notice that your template function is:

```
template <typename>
int check(int x)
```

If you change it to this:

```
template <typename T>
int check(T x)
```

then check<>(10) should be fine because the complier can know the type from the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't pass a template argument, it is equivalent to looking for the function without a template argument (i.e. it doesn't instantiate the template). The added `<>` means nothing in this case because there are is no overloading.

Since the function you have doesn't actually use the template for anything and the compiler thus can't infer the type T, but if you write it like this:

```
template <typename T>
T check(T x) {
    return x * 2;
}
```

Then all 3 cases will work, since it infers the type `T`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/797632/888641 for more explanation.

Note: You can use `typename` or `class`, they do the exact same thing here.

Comment: Thanks! The reason I added "<>" is that in Vandevoorde's "C++ Templates: The Complete Guilde" book it is written that call like "check<>" would force using template version of the function (it was mentioned there in context of function template overloading)

Comment: It doesn't mean nothing. If you had an overload, it would then prefer the template instead of the otherwise matching overload.

Comment: SO if there is no overload, it just means nothing?

Comment: @user1090010 If there exists a template version *and* a non-template or specialized version then adding `<>` tells the compiler to use the template version.

Answer (score 0):

I have to say that usually template doesn't go that way:(

Try this one:

```
template<typename T>
T check(T x){
    return x*2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`#2` would be valid if the template argument could be deduced.

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
void foo(T t)
{
    std::cout << "Template " << t << '\n';
}

void foo(int n)
{
    std::cout << "Not template " << n << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    foo(10); //calls non-template function 
             //because matching non-template preferred over function templates

    foo<>(10); //calls the template function, empty brackets indicate you want
               //the template overload, type is deduced from passed argument.

}
```

Another possibility, if the function template had default arguments (only legal in C++11).

```
template <class T = void>
int foo()
{
    return 10;
}

int main()
{
    return foo<>(); //same as foo<void>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only template instantiation you'll get is with

```
check<double>(10)
```

The others don't instantiate the template.   Also for the full power of function templates include the template argument as

```
template<typename T>
T check(T x) {
  return x*2;
}
```

Then using the power of template argument deduction you can call

```
check(10.0);   // instantiates check<dobule>
check(3);      // instantiates check<int>
```

or

```
a = MyObject();
check(a);         // instantiates check<MyObject>
```