# Designing template class with generic private member

Tags: c++, templates, type-inference

I suppose some other folks ran into this design issue before so I hope someone could give me some advice on what to do: I have a class that is supposed to hold a private generic object. As far as I can tell, I can't get away without making the entire class a template. FINE. But now, is there any way to infer the type of the underlying object during construction from the constructor parameter, without explicitly specifying it (I want to omit the template parameter, `Derived`, when I instantiate the `Test` class):

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Generic
{
};

class Derived : public Generic<int>
{
public:
    Derived ();
    int GetFoo ();
private:
    int m_foo;
};

template <typename T>
class Test
{
public:
    Test (T &underlying);
private:
    T m_underlying;
};

Derived::Derived ()
{
    this->m_foo = 666;
}

int Derived::GetFoo ()
{
    return this->m_foo;
}

template<typename T>
Test<T>::Test (T &underlying) : m_underlying(underlying)
{
    std::cout << this->m_underlying.GetFoo() << std::endl;
}

int main ()
{
    Derived underlying;
    Test<Derived> test(underlying);

    return 0;
}
```

Is there any other design strategy that I should be aware of, in order to achieve my goal?

Comment: @KerrekSB I'd rather not involve BOOST at this point, if I can help it... I mean, am I asking for too much from C++?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/797594/when-a-compiler-can-infer-a-template-parameter

Comment: I won't argue, but *that* amount of fear of Boost is anything but healthy. Haha. "Any"... get it?

Comment: @KerrekSB Very funny, mister :)

Comment: Well, in earnest, a class such as `boost::any` can be written in about ten lines, so it's really to your detriment to close yourself off against the idea. You can always roll your own code under the "as if Boost" rule, of course, but there *are* some useful ideas in Boost.

Comment: @KerrekSB I do agree, but then my code should have entire sections rewritten to make a full BOOST integration. Otherwise, it just looks like some spaghetti with bits and pieces of BOOST here and there. Yes, I'm using `boost/property_tree` for parsing XML, for example, since I'm not insane to write my own, but I'd like to spend some time and actually learn how to write code that follows the BOOST guidelines, before going all the way and making a mess of things...

Comment: @bshields Nasty. I was hoping to have a cleaner alternative... Oh well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually you have a class template together with a type-deducing *function* template:

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
    Foo(T const &);
};

template <typename T>
Foo<T> make_foo(T const & t)
{
    return Foo<T>(t);
}
```

Usage:

```
auto foo = make_foo(1728);   // makes a Foo<int>
```

This idea is used countless times in the standard library (such as `make_pair`, `make_tuple`, `make_shared`). The guiding principle is that you should say the desired typename at most one time, and not at all if it can be inferred.

Comment: Thanks. Too bad I won't be able to make use of the class constructor directly :(

Answer (score 3):

Just make a function to create `Test` object:

```
template <typename T> 
Test<T> make_test(T& underlying)
{
    return Test<T>(underlying);
}

int main ()
{
    Derived underlying;
    auto test = make_test(underlying);

    return 0;
}
```