# Infer function template parameter from a subclass of a template argument

Tags: c++, templates

My problem is similar to [When a compiler can infer a template parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797594/when-a-compiler-can-infer-a-template-parameter), but a little more complex.

I want to create a factory function, which deduces the type of its result so that I don't have to write it myself, but use auto instead (as in `auto b = ...` or `auto b3 = ...` below).

I can get the code to work with plain pointers, but when I change them to `unique_ptr`s compiler complains.

Here's the sample code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template <typename T>
struct A {
    T fA() const { return T(); }
};

struct Aint : A<int> {};

template <typename T>
struct B {
    B(std::unique_ptr<A<T>> ptr) : ptr_(std::move(ptr)) {}
    B(A<T>* ptr) : ptr_(ptr) {}
    std::unique_ptr<A<T>> ptr_;
};

template <typename T>
std::unique_ptr<B<T>> CreateB(A<T>* a) {
    return std::unique_ptr<B<T>>(new B<T>(a));
}

template <typename T>
std::unique_ptr<B<T>> CreateBFromUnique(std::unique_ptr<A<T>> a) {
    return std::unique_ptr<B<T>>(new B<T>(std::move(a)));
}

int main() {
    auto b = CreateB(new Aint);
    std::cout << b->ptr_->fA() << "\n";

    std::unique_ptr<Aint> a(new Aint);
    // call below fails to compile
    auto b2 = CreateBFromUnique(std::move(a));
    // This works fine.
    auto b3 = CreateBFromUnique<int>(std::move(a));
}
```

Here's clangs output (g++ prints a similar message):

```
templates1.cpp:34:15: error: no matching function for call to 'CreateBFromUnique'
    auto b2 = CreateBFromUnique(std::move(a));
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
templates1.cpp:24:23: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'A<type-parameter-0-0>' against 'Aint'
std::unique_ptr<B<T>> CreateBFromUnique(std::unique_ptr<A<T>> a) {
                      ^
```

How do I create a factory function that compiles here?

PS meta request: what is the canonical way to describe this problem so as to google it easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's more than one way to do it, of course, but...

```
#include <memory>

template <typename T> T AtypeHelper(A<T>*){}
template <typename T>
using Atype = decltype(AtypeHelper((T*)0));

template <typename U, typename T = Atype<U>>
  std::unique_ptr<B<T>> CreateBFromUnique(std::unique_ptr<U> a) {
  return MakeUnique<B<T>>(std::move(a));
}

int main() {
    auto b = CreateBFromUnique(MakeUnique<Aint>());
}
```

... You might also consider exporting a `typedef` from `A<T>` to make the `T` easily extractable as something like `typename U::value_type`.