# How to pass template function as argument of template function?

Tags: c++, templates

I wanna pass template function as argument of template function. In the 'meta_func_ok' function of the code below, successfully passed function pointer as argument of template function. But as template, No.

```
template    < typename N >  N
meta_func_ok( N( *f )( N ), N x ) {
    return f( x );
}

template    < typename F, typename N >  N
meta_func_ng( F f, N x ) {
    return f( x );
}

template    < typename N >  N
target_func( N x ) {
    return x;
}

int main() {
    meta_func_ok( target_func, 1 );
    meta_func_ng( target_func, 1 );     // LINE 18
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling this code generates error below.

> ng.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: ng.cpp:18:31: error: no matching
>   function for call to ‘meta_func_ng(, int)’   meta_func_ng( target_func, 1 );
>                                  ^ ng.cpp:7:1: note: candidate: template N meta_func_ng(F, N)  meta_func_ng( F f, N
>   x ) {  ^~~~~~~~~~~~ ng.cpp:7:1: note:   template argument
>   deduction/substitution failed: ng.cpp:18:31: note:   couldn't deduce
>   template parameter ‘F’   meta_func_ng( target_func, 1 );

How can I do? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiler support for type-inference is imperfect. In the second case (`meta_func_ng`)  the `N` type is inferred from the argument `1`, but `F` cannot be inferred from `target_func` because you don't specify an explicit type for `target_func`'s `N` type parameter (the compiler isn't smart-enough to know that `meta_func_ng`'s `N` is the same as `target_func`s `N`).

This works fine, however:

```
(same code as above here)

int main() {
    meta_func_ok( target_func, 1 );
    meta_func_ng( target_func<int>, 1 );     // LINE 18
    return 0;
}
```

See this QA: [When a compiler can infer a template parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797594/when-a-compiler-can-infer-a-template-parameter)